# Zip directory in BitBucket pipeline using image microsoft/dotnet:sdk

Tags: bitbucket-pipelines

In a `bitbucket-pipelines.yml` BitBucket Pipeline file I am trying to publish a DotNet Core solution, zip it into the correct form to be understood by AWS and then upload it S3.

My build is based on the image `microsoft/dotnet:sdk`.

```
image: microsoft/dotnet:sdk

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        caches:
          - dotnetcore
        script:
          - dotnet restore
          - dotnet publish MyProj/MyProj.csproj -o ../output
          - 7z a output.zip .\output\*
          - 7z a MyPackage.zip service.zip aws-windows-deployment-manifest.json
```

This step fails on the first `7z` command because 7Zip isn't installed. What is the best way from the Windows command line to zip these files? Alternatively, is there a different Docker image I should be using?

Comment: In Bitbucket Piplines you're not a Windows command line. You end up being in a Linux Docker container. So as @Alex Hinton suggested you can install zip or 7z using `apt-get`. Alternatively, if you have a lot to install, you can branch your own image from `microsoft/dotnet:sdk` and then prepare an image there that contains all your dependencies.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using Amazon.Lambda.Tools to deploy and had a similar issue where I needed to install zip - you could use zip to do it, or install 7z and use that - just need a couple of extra commands to apt-get

If you use a deployment step you'll also get CI/CD metrics and visuals in BitBucket (this is my config)

```
image: microsoft/dotnet:sdk

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        caches:
          - dotnetcore
        script:
          - dotnet restore
          - dotnet build
          - dotnet test
    - step:
        deployment: test
        script:
          - dotnet tool install -g Amazon.Lambda.Tools
          - export PATH="$PATH:/root/.dotnet/tools"
          - apt-get update
          - apt-get install zip -y # or install 7z instead
          - dotnet lambda deploy-serverless --region $...... # or manually upload to S3
```